# Can vim be made to only expand tabs to the left of text?

Tags: vim, alignment, indentation

Using vim, I would like to effectively have `expandtabs` off if I'm to the left of any text on the line and on if I'm to the right of any non-whitespace character.  (I would like to use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment.)

Can this be done?

Comment: I strongly believe it can be done. I just don't think it will be any easy, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use the [Smart Tabs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231) plugin.

> This script allows you to use your normal tab settings for the beginning of the line, and have tabs expanded as spaces anywhere else.  This effectively distinguishes 'indent' from 'alignment'.
>
> `<tab>`  Uses editor tab settings to insert a tab at the beginning of the line (before the first non-space character), and inserts spaces otherwise.
>
> `<BS>` Uses editor tab settings to delete tabs or 'expanded' tabs ala smarttab

To make Vim line up function arguments, add

```
set cindent
set cinoptions=(0,u0,U0
```

to `.vimrc`. The plugin will encode the whitespace as such:

```
int f(int x,
......int y) {
--->return g(x,
--->.........y);
}
```

This makes the alignment of "`x`" and "`y`" independent of the tab size (`tabstop`).

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
function! TabMaybeIndent()
    if strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1) =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return "    "
    endif
endfunction

set noexpandtab
imap <Tab> <C-r>=TabMaybeIndent()<CR>
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable approach.  With minor adjustments, you could even follow the current `softtabstop` setting instead of blindly inserting 4 spaces.